# Customer Order Totals

Tags: excel, vba

How would I execute a sub that allows me to determine a customer as defined by their (customer ID) to determine how much they have spent in total for over ($3000). As well as find the total spent by each  customer on the list and reports those whose total is more than the amount provided by the user on a new worksheet (Ex $3000) into a sheet that produces how much each customer spent along with their total amount spent to the right in a different cell.

Example of data:

[image: example data in excel]

current:

```
Sub test()

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "Report"


Lastrow = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Sheets("Data").Range("B3:B" & Lastrow).Copy

With Sheets("Report")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Activate
    .Range("B1").Select
    .Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Subtotal"
End With

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"), "=" & Cells(i, 1).Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C:C"))

Next

For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value < 3000 Then
        Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

Sheets("Report").Range("A1:B" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Sort KEY1:=Range("B1:B" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes


End Sub
```

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: I currently have the list revealing the customer id's and the amount totals but they seem to be repeating. As well I need to change the amount variable to be changed with a button on my main worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the trick.  I have not used dynamic ranges for the sake of saving me typing more, but these can be done.

```
Sub CustomerSpending(cusID as Integer, overAmount as Double)

  'Point it at the correct worksheet where your data is.  Don't use Activesheet
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Your Worksheet Name")

  Dim TotalCustomerSpend as Double 'This is your final figure

  'Loop through every ID in the list of data
  For Each ID In ws.Range("Specify Your column and range here")
    'Check if the ID matches the one you are looking for
    If ID = cusID Then
      'Look at the column 1 accross from the ID (The spending amount)
      'Check if the spending amount is greater than the amount you specified
      If ID.Offset(0,1).Value > overAmount Then
        'If the amount is greater than what you specified then add it to the total
        TotalCustomerSpend = TotalCustomerSpend + ID.Offset(0,1).Value
      End If
    End If
  Next ID
```

You can then call the sub with

```
Call CustomerSpending(192,3000.00)
```

This will return a sum of all spending for customer 192 over $3000.  For all spending do the following

```
Call CustomerSpending(192,0)
```

Which will report all spending by 192 over $0

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without re-inventing the wheel with VBA. Select the data and insert a Pivot table. This is basic Excel functionality that has been around for at least 20 years.

If you want to use VBA, create the Pivot Table with VBA.

Tip: before creating the pivot table, turn the source data table into an Excel Table object with Insert > Table (or Ctrl-T). Then create a pivot table from the Excel Table. That way the pivot data source will be dynamic and when you add more data to the source, you only need to refresh the pivot table to include the new data.